# Passing configuration values between multiple Golang programs

Tags: linux, go

I am interested in passing configuration values between multiple golang programs.

I have experimented with environment variables but they cannot be read by a different program than the one that set them.

I have tested and I am certain that the environment variable is being set and can be read in the same process that set it. Also, if I call the second process through the first it will print it:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)    

func main() {
    os.Setenv("AVARIABLE", "12345")

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    fmt.Print("Enter text: ")
    _, _ = reader.ReadString('\n')
    fmt.Println("exiting")
}
```

and

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("AVARIABLE"))
}
```

The environment variable context is too narrow for my purpose.

I am considering these options:

1. Create a file at `/etc/profile.d/<filename>.sh` and run `source /etc/profile.d/<filename>.sh` in order to set the variable more globally.
2. Create a file somewhere which anybody can read and avoid the environment variable issue.

Are there better ways? how should I proceed?

Comment: You can't set environment variables for another process. A process inherits its environment from its parent, and can only set its own variables.

Comment: Is my title too limited? It seems like this question is answered and I should create a new question.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/coreos/etcd it may be too heavyweight for your requirements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to share configuration that might change at runtime, then having a shared configuration file that is read in either periodically or whenever a change occurs. There are some mechanisms that you can use to notify you when a file changes, but those may be OS dependent.

Another option is to use some form of [inter-process communication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx) but that may be a bit much if all you want to do is share some config variables.

Comment: just want to add [info](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/6zhuuYpCg8Y) about the location for the config file.